# Anomaly in VTGate QPS

Tags: mysql, sharding, vitess

I am running multiple application servers and AWS Network load-balancers against 12 VTGates. I see following anomaly in VTGates.

[image: VTGate1]

[image: VTGate2]

Sometimes QPS suddenly drops to 0.

Not too sure what is happening exactly. Hope someone can point out if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: But vitess continues to serve fine? Maybe the load balancer stops sending queries to that vtgate? Can you check the other vtgates? Longer term, you should setup prometheus to consolidate from all vtgates.

Comment: Could you point out good documentation for this?

Comment: There is a contribution from Slack about how they've setup prometheus here https://github.com/vitessio/vitess/tree/master/vitess-mixin

Comment: Do you have the slowlog turned on?